# Inspecting a drop down list when it is changed is not showing the correct value

Tags: c#, asp.net

This winforms code:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Item 1");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Item 2");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Item 3");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Item 4");
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = comboBox1.Text;
    }
```

works perfectly. I select one item and the textbox display the same content of the combobox

Now the same for ASP.NET:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DropDownList1.Items.Add("Item 1");
        DropDownList1.Items.Add("Item 2");
        DropDownList1.Items.Add("Item 3");
        DropDownList1.Items.Add("Item 4");
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = DropDownList1.Text;
    }
```

In this case, the textbox stays empty. Why?

Comment: Shouldn't `TextBox1.Text` be `textBox1.Text`?  C# is case-sensitive.

Comment: @Tim Presumably he named his `TextBox` variable `TextBox1`, not `textbox1`.  Otherwise it wouldn't compile, rather than compile and not run.

Comment: Can you include the related markup for the 2nd snippet? Web applications require another HTTP request (typically via PostBack in Web Forms) for server code to respond to a user interaction. Is the `<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" />` using [`AutoPostBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback.aspx)?

Comment: @Tim in C# (for desktop) textBox1 is lowercase "t". In C# (for ASP.NET)  TextBox1.Text is Uppercase "T". Also comboBox is renamed DropDownList. This are very stupid incoerencies but is just like that.

Comment: @user3154407: Sorry, but those "very stupid incoerencies" aren't actually correct.  You can name your variables/controls/etc. whatever you like.  The C# language doesn't change between WinForms and ASP.NET.  The convention is to begin variable names with a lowercase letter.  The WebForms designer you're using may not do that, but it should.  (You should rename them both anyway, `textBox1` isn't a particularly meaningful name.)  And a `ComboBox` is not "renamed `DropDownList`.  Those are two very different controls which do different things.

Answer (score 4):

When you change your selection, does the page post back to the server?

The difference isn't in C#, it's in the architecture of the application.  WinForms is a single application running on a single machine.  So when an event happens, the entire application knows about it.  WebForms, on the other hand, is actually *two* things separated by a network connection.  There's the server-side code, and the client-side code.  Unless the server-side code is invoked by a request of some kind, it can't interact with the client-side code.

So it's not that the code isn't working, it's that when you change the selection on the `DropDownList` it needs to notify the server of this event somehow.  One way to do that is to set it to auto-postback:

```
DropDownList1.AutoPostBack = true;
```

This would make the behavior a little more consistent with what you're expecting in that it immediately notifies the server-side code that the selection has changed.  *However*, in a web application this results in an undesirable user experience.  Constantly posting the page back to the server is, well, ugly.  And it hurts performance a lot.

You can use some JavaScript code to perform your logic client-side.  Or perhaps make AJAX requests to server-side resources (HttpHandlers usually, in WebForms), again using JavaScript, to perform server-side processing and retrieve a result of some kind.  This continues to exemplify the separation between client-side and server-side.  JavaScript code, running in the browser context, is fully aware of the eventing model of the page and can immediately respond to a selection change in a `select` element.

Ultimately you're not seeing a difference in how the C# language works.  What you're seeing is a fundamental difference in how web applications work vs. how desktop applications work.  Web applications, regardless of how much WebForms has tried to obscure this over the years, are request/response systems between a client and a server.  In order for the server-side code to run, a request must be sent.

Comment: Yes David is correct. You need to have have this in codefront: <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the current value of the DropDownlist, which Item is the current selected one....

Comment: Just to expand, it's not the language which is different it's two very different controls which happen to look similar which behave differently.

Comment: Presumably the user is selecting one; there is no need for the code to do so.

Answer (score 0):

On asp.net the dropdownlist saves the list on viewstate, and you must not add them again on post back , or else you reset the selection. To make it work as you expect add the IsPostBack check as:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            DropDownList1.Items.Add("Item 1");
            DropDownList1.Items.Add("Item 2");
            DropDownList1.Items.Add("Item 3");
            DropDownList1.Items.Add("Item 4");
        }
    }
```

Also the selection are taken from  SelectedValue

```
  protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    }
```

If you have disable the viewstate for the page or for this control, you can always direct what this control is post back by using the `.Form` as

```
Request.Form[DropDownList1.UniqueID]
```